# Javascript on success function issue

Tags: javascript

I have this js code and i need on "success" to trigger the document.getElementById('light') and document.getElementById('fade') but is not working, some help please?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
        //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    }

}); 

})();       

$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ $('.percent-success').fadeOut() }, 3000);
});

document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
</script>
```

Comment: Pls provide given Errors and clear out what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but could you not just copy the lines in the `success: function() {}` part of the code? Where you placed it, it will be executed when the `<script>` tag is loaded.